# How can I use dependency injection for my own service in blazor component class

Tags: blazor

How can I use dependency injection for my own service in blazor component class?

Component class:

```
[Inject]
public HttpContentFormatter IHttpContentFormatter { 
     get; 
     set; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Supposing your app is client-side Blazor, you should add your object to the DI container as following:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContentFormatter>();

        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
```

And in your Component you inject the object like that:

```
@inject IHttpContentFormatter HttpContentFormatter
```

Comment: The ConfigureServices part would be the same for Server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContentFormatter, HTTPContentFormatter>();

    }
```

The second type parameter to the AddXxxx methods is the concrete type that you want to implement the IHttpContentFormatter interface.  then the @Inject declaration works just like you say.